# Rasterio : rasterio.drivers() - 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, rasterio, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to pass a script on jupyter-hub with a specific kernel. With my last local installation it worked but now with my kernel I have this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-f1a418595338> in <module>()
      4 
      5 mask = None
----> 6 with rasterio.drivers():
      7     with rasterio.open(B2_reclass_path) as src:
      8         image = src.read(1) # first band

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I don't really understand this error and I didn't find a solution anywhere

Comment: `rasterio.drivers()` method is outdated. Because of getting the error is that `rasterio` has a module named `drivers` now. A module is not used with `()`.